# Can not sync private project to Travis CI from Github

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I am using Travis CI to run script of repository github, but i can not see my private project to sync
Anything i can make to do it ?
https://gyazo.com/1086bc83f8b91ce38c74618c38df7705

Answer (score 1):

In Travis CI, private and public repos are separately managed. Public repositories appear in https://travis-ci.org/profile and private ones in https://magnum.travis-ci.com/profile.

For more details you can refer to https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2519